# A Formal Grammar: defining English counting numbers?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, context-sensitive

I would like to define a grammar that produces and recognizes the counting numbers of the English language.  I created the production rules below based on the assumption this is *context-free*, but I am not entirely sure thats the case.  Is this a *context-free* or *context-sensitive* grammar?  If context-free, do my production rules look ok?

For example:

"one hundred twenty two" $\in \Sigma^*$ which has the semantic meaning $b^2+2b^1+2b^0$

"one thousand two hundred thirty three" $\in \Sigma^*$, $b^3+2b^2+3b^1+3b^0$

I understand context-free production rules are $N \rightarrow \alpha$ and context-sensitive $\alpha N \beta \rightarrow \alpha \gamma \beta$, where $N$ is a non-terminal and $\alpha,\gamma$ are terminals or non-terminals.

I considered CFG production rules in Backus Naur Form as follows, but am unsure if it's correct:

```
<S> := "zero" | <b3> | <thou> | <mill> | <bill> | ""
<num99> := <ones> | <teens> | <tens> | <tens> <ones>
<num99opt> := <num99> | ""
<b3> := <ones> "hundred" <num99opt> | <num99> 
<b3op> := <b3> | ""
<thou> := <b3> "thousand" <b3op>
<thouop> := <thou> | <b3op>
<mill> := <b3> "million" <thouop>
<millop>:= <mill> | <thouop>
<bill> := <b3> "billion" <millop>
<tens> := "twenty" | "thirty" | ... | "ninety" 
<teens> := "ten" | "eleven" | ... | "nineteen"
<ones> := "one" | "two" | ... | "nine"
```

Comment: "I understand context-free production rules are $N→α$ and context-sensitive $αNβ→αγβ$." Ok, in that case why do you have any doubt about whether your grammar is context-free? Or do you mean that you are not sure that the *language* is context-free, which is a different question (but the answer is that it is).

Comment: I note the supplied grammar is CFG, however am unsure it is correct to generate the grammar described.  Given your comment, it appears this is a CFG.

Comment: @rici I updated the grammar, appreciate any feedback

Comment: That grammar looks fine (and obviously could be extended for larger numbers). Note that there are only a finite number of derivable phrases. (It's a large number, but it's still finite.) All finite languages are regular (and therefore context free, because regular languages are a strict subset of context free languages).

Comment: Thanks.  I suspect the grammar produces finite derivations because of the largest prefix, i.e. "million", "billion", "trillion".  I'm confused why it is regular.  I saw that regular grammars are defined such that the production rules are in the form $A \rightarrow aB$ or $A \rightarrow a$, where $A,B \in N$ and $a \in \Sigma^*$ and where only a single non-terminal is allowed on the RHS.  The above grammar has multiple non-terminals on the RHS, so differs from the definition of a regular grammar.  Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not a regular grammar. But the language it generates is a regular language, which means that there exists a regular grammar for the same language. (And, yes, it's finite because there is a largest number it can produce. If you added quadrillion, quintillion, etc., you would increase the size of the language, but it would still be finite. The language of decimal integers, however, is not finite: there is no largest integer. (It's still a regular language, though.)

Comment: Wiki defines a finite language as regular and like you say this language is finite and therefore regular.  I think thats important because a FSA vs PDA can recognize it, which means that it can be recognized without stack memory and only states.  Is the next step to convert to a DFA using the standard NFA to DFA algorithm?  Or should the grammar somehow be rewritten to be regular?

Comment: Yes, it can be recognised by an FSA, although that might have a lot of states. But I strongly suspect that you don't just want to recognise whether or not a phrase is valid. You probably want to understand the number that it represents; at least, that type of semantic analysis is what parsing is usually about. And for parsing, you'll probably find that the CFG is closer to the representation.